# Name of the song in episode 11 of Nanatsu no Taizai (The Seven Deadly Sins)?

Tags: music, seven-deadly-sins

I am searching for the name of a song or soundtrack which plays in the background in episode 11 of Nanatsu no Taizai. It starts at 17:48. I have already searched through the whole Nanatsu no Taizai OST, but I couldn't find it, so if someone knows the name please let me know.

Comment: There are [two OST CDs](http://vgmdb.net/search?q=nanatsu+no+taizai), did you check both? Otherwise it's also possible, it was never released.

Comment: yes i checked both but i didn't find it. And i thought every song that plays in the anime has to be in the ost...but maybe i am wrong..

Comment: No, not necessarily unfortunately. However, that doesn't mean this has to be the case here, maybe there are more albums not listed on vgmdb.

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever find it? If not, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOHKyGrD_v8.

The name of the song is *Kurai & Setsunai-4 Taizai* (9雷&セ2内-4:罪), track 11 of The Seven Deadly Sins ORIGINAL SOUNDTRACK 2.